# python pandas - sumf if rolling arguments

Tags: python, pandas, sum, apply

I hope you could help me as I relatively new to python.
My dataframe looks like the following:

[image]

Now, I would like to calculate a sumif of the Quantity, with the conditions:

Date, Delivery Beg, Buy/Sell, Trader

As a minimum example (only considering one condition) I tried the following:

```
 deals["Accumulated Buy"]=deals.apply(lambda x: x["Quantity"] if  x["Delivery Beg"]==x["Delivery   Beg"] else 0, axis=1)
```

which of course only gives me the quantity of this specific row but not the sum of all quantities where the condition applies. The problem is that I my conditions are rolling, i.e. first the code should sum the quantities of all deals done on 19/11 with Delivery Beg 02:00. Afterwards the same should be done for the conditions in row 2 or row n. I tried something like that:

```
for i in deals.index:
deals["Accumulated Buy"]=deals.apply(lambda x: x["Quantity"] if  x["Delivery Beg"]==x["Delivery Beg"].iloc[i] else 0, axis=1)
```

However, here I get:

```
AttributeError: ("'datetime.time' object has no attribute 'iloc'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

Can anybody help me on this?

TX!!

EDIT: Ok, I would like to have the sum of the quantity of all Sell deals done on the 19.11.2014 with a Delivery Beg 02:00:00, in the table above this would be -3,6 + -2,5 = -6,1. 
May the next column looks like the following:

[image]

Then in row 3, 4, the sum of all sell deals done on the 19th with Delivery Beg 02:15 should be calculated i.e.(-15,9) in row 5,6 all buy deals done on the 19th with Delivery Beg 02:30 and in row 7 all buy deals done on the 19th with Delivery Beg 02:45.

This means that my conditions change row by row.

I hope it is clearer now. The function should calculate the sumif with the changing conditions for each row.

Basic idea: I would like to know who (Trader) bought and sold (Buy/sell) which volume (sum of quantity) in which quarter (Delivery Beg)
Thanks!

Comment: To clarify.  You want to do a sum when the values of a row are the same?   Also, its sometimes helpful to post an example of the desired outcome on a a question like this

Comment: so simple `groupby...sum` should work

Comment: yes agree but how to change the conditions automatically, --> loop about a list of conditions?

Comment: @Johannes I don't get it, what answer you want to get?

Comment: @ Roman, you are right I was stupid. Of course a groupby works. However when using groupby over the "Delivery Beg" I get an error: unorderable types: float() > datetime.time()     Do you know why? Should I set Date + Delivery Beg as index and group by the index?

Comment: could you narrow your error a bit? If you can create small dataframe and reproduce an error on it - post it here and we'll help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you're need *rolling* sum. Could it be that simple `deals.groupby` will be enough? like this:

```
df.groupby(['Date', 'Trader', 'Buy/Sell', 'Delivery Beg'])['Quantity'].sum()
```

If you want then get rolling sum, you can use `cumsum()` function on it.

```
>>> df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=';')
>>> df
         Date Delivery Beg Buy/Sell  Quantity Trader
0  19.11.2014     02:00:00        S      -3.6   TRD1
1  19.11.2014     02:00:00        S      -2.5   TRD1
2  19.11.2014     02:15:00        S      -2.3   TRD1
3  19.11.2014     02:15:00        S     -13.6   TRD1
4  19.11.2014     02:30:00        B       9.1   TRD1
5  19.11.2014     02:30:00        B       0.1   TRD1
6  19.11.2014     02:45:00        S      19.9   TRD1
>>> df.groupby(['Date', 'Trader', 'Buy/Sell', 'Delivery Beg'])['Quantity'].sum()
Date        Trader  Buy/Sell  Delivery Beg
19.11.2014  TRD1    B         02:30:00         9.2
                    S         02:00:00        -6.1
                              02:15:00       -15.9
                              02:45:00        19.9
```

Or, if you want to get the data as a columns and not as index:

```
>>> df.groupby(['Date', 'Trader', 'Buy/Sell', 'Delivery Beg'])['Quantity'].sum().reset_index()
         Date Trader Buy/Sell Delivery Beg  Quantity
0  19.11.2014   TRD1        B     02:30:00       9.2
1  19.11.2014   TRD1        S     02:00:00      -6.1
2  19.11.2014   TRD1        S     02:15:00     -15.9
3  19.11.2014   TRD1        S     02:45:00      19.9
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you mean, but I guess that you have some conditions on the columns Date, Delivery Beg, Buy/Sell, and Trader. Lets call these conditions a, b, c, d, and e, respectively. When They are fulfilled you would like to sum the quantity. If so my suggestion would be

```
df.Quantity[(df['Date']==a) & (df['Delivery Beg']==b) & (and so on)].cumsum()
```

If some of the conditions are a lists, and only one of the elements must be fulfilled use, e.g. `df['Date'].isin(YourListOfConditions)`.

Comment: yes this would work but how can I do that for changing criteria, i.e. for 96 different Delivery Begs with a buy and sell for each of this Delivery Beg: 19/11/2014 00:00 S -10 | 19/11/2014 00:00 B 5| 19/11/2014 00:15 S -20 | 19/11/2014 00:15 B 12

Comment: Now you could loop over the list of criteria, like `[df.Quantity[(df['Date']==a) & (df['Delivery Beg']==b) & (and so on)].sum() for b in df['Delivery Beg']]`. Btw, if looping takes to long. you can use pivot to use 'Delivery Beg' as a column index and then take the sum for each column. E.g. `df = pd.DataFrame({'Quantity': [1,2,3,4,], 'val2': ['a', 'f', 'c', 'r'], 'date': [dt.time(2,4,5), dt.time(2,6,10), dt.time(3,7,5),dt.time(3,40,5)]})`. Then `df[['Quantity','date']].pivot(index=df.index,columns='date').sum()`. Though not memory efficient, I found it often much faster than groupby.